# How can I change the version (default-series) that Juju deploys?

Tags: juju, maas

I have installed MAAS server on one machine and have two other nodes. In the web interface of the MAAS server I have set distro to 13.10 and commissioning to 13.10.  When I use juju bootstrap it installs 12.04 release to the nodes.

Why is this happening. Can you give me some advices?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `default-series` environment config setting defaults to `precise`, because almost all the charms in the store are written for precise, and so juju is picking charms for precise and deploying them to precise.

If you want to deploy to saucy, you should change your `environments.yaml` file:

```
environments:
    myenv:
        type: maas
        default-series: saucy
        ...
```

...but you'll need to make sure you have charms that run on saucy, so you'll almost certainly need to write them yourself (or maybe try copying the existing ones for precise?) and deploy them from a [local repository](https://juju.ubuntu.com/docs/charms-deploying.html#local).